# An SVG property that is respected only when inline, not through CSS

Tags: html, svg

Supposedly, [all SVG presentation attributes can be used as CSS properties.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute)

And yet `preserveAspectRatio` appears to be observed only when it is an inline property, not through CSS.

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; }
.wrapper {
    width: 50%; height: 10%;
}
.box {
    padding: 10px; margin: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #888; border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #eee; color: #000;

    position: relative;
}
rect.rfoo { fill: #8af; }

svg.myrect1 {
    position: absolute;
    preserveAspectRatio: none;
    left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;
}
svg.myrect2 {
    position: absolute;
    left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box wrapper">
    <svg class="myrect1" viewBox="0 0 300 200">
        <rect class="rfoo" x="25" y="25" width="250" height="150"></rect>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="box wrapper">
    <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" class="myrect2" viewBox="0 0 300 200">
        <rect class="rfoo" x="25" y="25" width="250" height="150"></rect>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preserveAspectRatio` is **not** a [presentation attribute](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#PresentationAttributes).

Comment: Also note that some presentation attributes have been defined as such only in SVG2, which is not yet fully implemented by all browsers.

Comment: So there are some attributes that one can use for `<img src="file.svg">`, others that one can use for `<svg attr="value">...</svg>`, and yet others that one can use for `<svg class="name">...</svg>`. Never mind the first. That would be too broad. Is there any logic to the separation between the second and the third, one that would allow us to code for some length of time without constantly searching online for answers?